# How to appeal the deletion of a comment thread?

Tags: support, comment, deletion

A thread of comments was deleted in bulk, including extensive clarifications to notation used in the answer.

How can this decision be appealed/reversed?

Comment: If a moderator deleted those comments you can appeal to us by flagging the post the comments were attached to. If a regular user decided to delete their comments, there's nothing we can do.

Comment: Were the clarifications edited into the answer? If so, there's no point in undeleting the comments...

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4602/are-deleted-comments-destroyed?rq=1